# Is it a must to convert pandas dataframe to numpy arrays for machine learning algorithms in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Is it a must to convert pandas dataframe to numpy arrays for machine learning algorithms in scikit-learn ?

I know the `to_numpy()` function does the conversion. This would mean I have to manually create a dummy matrix for categorical columns in pandas dataframe too.

What happens if I just use pandas dataframe as input in scikit-learn ? And If I convert pandas dataframe to numpy arrays, then does it means my column names is no longer preserved in the machine learning algorithm ? When it comes to model diagnostics, extra steps need to be taken to reconcile the column names with numpy arrays?

Comment: If the function says it takes a dataframe ....   But if it says `array` it may use `np.asarray` to ensure it is that.  You can read the code to be sure.  Check what that does. It may delegate the action to `to_numpy`.  Read the docs, and where it's unclear read the [source].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supplying an array of floats is a safe bet, but it's not a must. Whatever you supply will be attempted to convert to numpy array internally. If it's not an array-like (see below) an exception will be raised.

If you take [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)  as an example, you'll find out in `sklearn` they have a notion of an `array-like`. See for example docstring for [`RandomForestRegressor.fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.fit):

> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
> The training input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted to dtype=np.float32. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted into a sparse csc_matrix.

You can gain a further insight of what is an `array-like` by reading [glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-array-like):

> **array-like**
> The most common data format for input to Scikit-learn estimators and functions, array-like is any type object for which numpy.asarray will produce an array of appropriate shape (usually 1 or 2-dimensional) of appropriate dtype (usually numeric).
>
> This includes:
>
> - a numpy array
> - a list of numbers
> - a list of length-k lists of numbers for some fixed length k
> - a pandas.DataFrame with all columns numeric
> - a numeric pandas.Series
>
> It excludes:
>
> - a sparse matrix
> - an iterator
> - a generator

If you go through the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L303), you'll found out that the data you supply to your methods will flow through `self._validate_data` that will make conversion for you.

You can always check beforehand if your data is acceptable by [`sklearn.utils.check_array`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_array.html#sklearn.utils.check_array), but it doesn't make too much practical sense because it will be done for you anyways when you supply your data to a method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I supply numpy arrays, then the column names are not preserved and I will have to reconcile the column names with the numpy arrays after model fitting . Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes if you need them. No otherwise.